# How to redirect python path to find files on Desktop

Tags: python

This may be a simple fix, but after researching online I could not find the answer I was looking for.

So I have a file (which is on my Desktop) that I am trying to check the version status of, but the interpreter cannot find it in its path

code: python -m spacetime --version

My python interpreter follows this long file path

[image]

From my understanding, the python interpreter has to point, or know the path of the file we are trying to check for.

But how do I either 1. point to the file, or 2. change the path of the  interpreter?

Answer (score 0):

You have not installed spacetime lib. You need to install it at first:

```
pip install spacetime
```

and [here](https://pypi.org/project/spacetime/) the little instructions about 'how to install reqienments'